# Python get specific characters from a list

Tags: python

I want the following output from a list:

```
['3', '7', '3', '7', '9', '14', '15']
```

The list i'm using is:

```
['9:3;', '15:7', '9:3,', '15:7,', '9', '104:14,', '15']
```

So i only want the numbers after the `:` but i need 9 and the 15 as well.
Is there a way for this?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this is not a site where you can just give coding work to other people. You are welcome to post, what you have tried, and we are glad to help you correct your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be neatly handled with a comprehension list:

```
new_list = [x.split(':')[-1] for x in original_list]
```

This will split the string at each `:` and then only keep the latter half. This will also work if no `:` is in the string.